# Array Always Returning Null

Tags: android, google-maps, multidimensional-array, null, nullpointerexception

I'm making an Android app that reads a file from a folder, generates an array from it, then plots the array's latitude + longitude points on a map.  I at first developed the array returning method as a void method in a seperate program (and it functioned properly).  The only changes I made to it was that I made it return the array, so that the android app can use it.  However, I always got force closes.  After some debugging, I found that my method was returning 'null' everytime (I set an if statement saying that if the array is null, display a screen that says "FAIL!" - and the app always is showing "FAIL!").

I checked to make sure that the file is located in the right spot - it definitely is.  Still, I'm unsure as to why the program is returning null? Here's some of my code:

```
package net.learn2develop.GoogleMaps;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView.LayoutParams;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;


public class MapsActivity extends MapActivity 
{    
    MapView mapView; 
    MapController mc;
    GeoPoint p;
    GeoPoint p2;
    GeoPoint p99;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Map code goes here.....


    // Add points from ReadCsv.java
    File fileToUse = new File("/Users/csrobot/Desktop/TrainingData/Training4.csv");
    String[][] bump = getArray(fileToUse);
    if(bump == null){
        setContentView(R.layout.deleteme);
    }
//      for(int i = 0; i < bump.length; i++) {
//          String coordinates99[] = {bump[i][0], bump[i][1]};
//          double lat99 = Double.parseDouble(coordinates99[0]);
//          double lng99 = Double.parseDouble(coordinates99[1]);
//          p99 = new GeoPoint(
//                  (int) (lat99 * 1E6),
//                  (int) (lng99 * 1E6));
//          MapOverlay mapOverlay99 = new MapOverlay();
//          List<Overlay> listOfOverlays99 = mapView.getOverlays();
//          listOfOverlays99.add(mapOverlay99);
//      } 

    mapView.invalidate();
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}

public String[][] getArray(File file) {

    try {
        int row = 0;
        int col = 0;
        String[][] numbers=new String[5258][16];

        BufferedReader bufRdr;
        bufRdr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line = null;

        //read each line of text file
        while((line = bufRdr.readLine()) != null) {
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line,",");
            col=0;

            while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                //get next token and store it in the array
                numbers[row][col] = st.nextToken();
                col++;
            }
            row++;
        }

        // ... Here is the code that will make the array
                    // ...   

        //close the file
        bufRdr.close();

        return arrayOfBumps;

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(Exception e) {
                // System.out.println("The following error occurred "+e);
    }
    return null;

}
```

So that is what my activity looks like.  My logcat before adding the "if(bump == null)" statement and un-commenting the 'for' loop that follows it was:

```
07-28 09:11:10.962: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13014): FATAL EXCEPTION: main  
07-28 09:11:10.962: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13014): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.learn2develop.GoogleMaps/net.learn2develop.GoogleMaps.MapsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException  
07-28 09:11:10.962: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13014):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)  
07-28 09:11:10.962: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13014):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)  
07-28 09:11:10.962: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13014):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)  
07-28 09:11:10.962: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13014):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)  
07-28 09:11:10.962: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13014):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)  
07-28 09:11:10.962: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13014):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)  
07-28 09:11:10.962: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13014):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)  
07-28 09:11:10.962: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13014):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)  
07-28 09:11:10.962: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13014):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)  
07-28 09:11:10.962: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13014):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)  
07-28 09:11:10.962: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13014):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)  
07-28 09:11:10.962: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13014):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)  
07-28 09:11:10.962: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13014): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException  
07-28 09:11:10.962: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13014):     at net.learn2develop.GoogleMaps.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:89)  
07-28 09:11:10.962: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13014):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)  
07-28 09:11:10.962: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13014):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)  
07-28 09:11:10.962: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13014):     ... 11 more
```

So can anyone help me out here?  I've been at this for a few days and still can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`File fileToUse = new File("/Users/csrobot/Desktop/TrainingData/Training4.csv");`

This is the source of the `NullPointerException`.

The path of the file must be in this form `/data/data/yourpackagename/somefolder/yourfile`

You cant do this like this. The file must be stored inside Emulator/phone data storage. You must push the file to the emulator data, like moving your csv file into `assets/raw resource` and then load it into `InputStreamReader` object and do what you have planned to do. Search for some more examples of openning file from `assets` folder or `res/raw` folder

Comment: I put the csv file in my assets folder.  I looked up 2 examples already but but one says to do something like "Activity.getAssets().open(...)".  I'm a little confused here.